# React form validation for multiple field

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React. I have a very simple form which contains employer address details. I would like to validate if any of the fields got value, then check if length is <=10 and if not exists the it is fine. There are no mandatory validation and only length valiation if exists.

currently doing like below:

```
  const isValid=
    employer.address == null ||
    (employer.address != null &&
      (employer.address.building?.length <= 2) &&
      employer.address.street?.length <= 2 &&
      employer.address.county?.length <= 2 &&
      employer.address.city?.length <= 2 &&
      employer.address.postcode?.length <= 2);
```

Is there a better way to test to check validation if it contains value and ignore if not.

Comment: You can also use the standard html attributes for this, for example the minLength prop in the input would do the validation for you and won't allow clicking the submit unless the input is less than two and the maxLength would help you with this minus 10 characters condition

Comment: Use validators like Yup.

Comment: But i dont want these fileds to be required field. want to validate the length only if any text exists

Answer (score 1):

it is neither bad nor the best way

with current code you can do a bit clean Up to make it look nicer
you can assign a const to employer.address so no need to repeat it

```
const emp = employer.address
const isValid=
    !emp||
    (emp&&
      (emp.building?) &&
      emp.street?&&
      emp.county?&&
      emp.city? &&
      emp.postcode?);
```

in the example above validation works if data is `''` but if it has anything inside it (`'s'`) validation would not be called
i think it should work same way

also there are some packages that provide you validation

redux form
https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/

yup
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup